# Separate a string into numeric values

Tags: javascript

I have a string like 1.1.2 . What I need is I need to separate the numeric values and take the values 1, 1, 2 separately. Better If I can put the 3 values into an array. Could someone please suggest me a way.

Ex: If the value is 1.2 I should be able to get 1 and 2 separately.

Then If it is 1.10 should be able to get 1 and 10 separately..

1.10.11 then the values must me 1 , 10 and 11

Comment: You can use `split('.')`. It will return an array of string

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var data = "1.10.11";
var arr = data.split('.');
for(i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
    alert(arr[i])
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LErSB/1/)

If you to use it as int, you can convert it using `parseInt()`

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "1.1.2"
a = string.split(".")
```

will split it to [1,1,2]

if you also want to parse it to int do the following

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  a[i] = parseInt(a[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using split, you can do something like this...

```
var s = "1.4.2.6.10";
nums = s.split('.');

alert (nums[4]);
```

`nums` is an array, and you can access any value of the array using `nums[0]`, `nums[1]`, etc.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UsukUriB/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string .split method with a period as the delimiter. It will return an array of strings by default .split"."

Answer (score 1):

this can be done very simply;

```
var string="1.2.13";
var split=string.split(".");
console.log(split); //[1,2,13]
console.log(split[1]) //2
```